# Can you say 'wrap into...'?

Tags: phrases, expressions, word-usage

In dictionaries I only find the phrase **to wrap something up**, I can't find any phrase that would express what you wrap something up in.

If you want to express in what you wrap something up, can you say **wrap something (up) into something**?

You could probably say that you wrap something up **with** something, but could you also say, for example:

> I wrapped the present **into** the wrapping paper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the usual preposition is "in", not "into":

> I wrapped up the present in wrapping paper.

You could say "I put the present into the wrapping paper",  but that is not what the verb "wrap" requires.